# curl usage to get header

Tags: linux, curl

Why does this not work:

```
curl -X HEAD http://www.google.com
```

But these both work just fine:

```
curl -I http://www.google.com

curl -X GET http://www.google.com
```

Answer (score 126, accepted):

You need to add the -i flag to the first command, to include the HTTP header in the output. This is required to print headers.

```
curl -X HEAD -i http://www.google.com
```

More here: https://serverfault.com/questions/140149/difference-between-curl-i-and-curl-x-head

Comment: it does work but does not return. The second answer actually does.

Answer (score 55):

`curl --head https://www.example.net`

I was pointed to this by curl itself; when I issued the command with `-X HEAD`, it printed:

```
Warning: Setting custom HTTP method to HEAD with -X/--request may not work the 
Warning: way you want. Consider using -I/--head instead.
```

Comment: See https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2015/09/11/unnecessary-use-of-curl-x/ for an explanation of the message.

Comment: Fits like gloves

Answer (score 4):

google.com is not responding to `HTTP HEAD` requests, which is why you are seeing a hang for the first command.

It does respond to `GET` requests, which is why the third command works.

As for the second, curl just prints the headers from a standard request.